# Compute $B=QAQ^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, $B=QAQ^{-1}$, and I know $A$ and $B$, how to compute $Q$?

I know if $T$ a linear transformation, and with different basis we get $A$ and $B$, and we could use these basis to compute $Q$, but how to compute if we only got the matrices?

Comment: @Alqatrkapa SVD only makes sense if $Q$ is assumed to be orthogonal/unitary

Comment: Note that $BQ - QA = 0$ is a linear system on $Q$ that can be solved directly.

Answer (score 1):

This amounts to finding an invertible solution $Q$ to the [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)
$$
BQ - QA = 0
$$

Answer (score -1):

You should use SVD decomposition in a such way you decompose them.

Comment: How does SVD help us solve this with, for example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&10\\0&-1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}?
$$
are you implying that arbitrary matrices can be diagonalized via SVD?